# Manga where a girl learns that her recently deceased grandmother could bring drawings to life. Winds up with a demon companion

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this as a translated comic on one of the manga sites (I don't recall exactly which one, but I don't think it was a licensed translation/presentation) somewhere in the last few years. A girl with typical westernish manga features is visiting the house of her grandmother (a mansion, more like) who has recently died. I believe said grandmother was the primary person who encouraged the girl's artwork. Somehow, she comes upon a secret space in the house, where she finds drawings by her grandmother, and she manages to bring them to life. One of the drawings is actually of her grandmother, which lets her get some answers about what is going on. She also winds up animating a former servant of her grandmother, a female demon (cute bat wings, curvaceous) who initially gloats, thinking there's no way the protagonist can bind her, only to find out that her gift is strong enough that she must serve. Shortly after that, the girl is attacked by small dive-bombing airplanes (biplanes?) which I think are sent by someone else who has the power to animate drawings. The three of them survive and escape the house, and that's where I left off, maybe a few chapters in.

I do not recall the hair-color of the girl, although I want to say it was a lighter color, and she was wearing a one-piece dress. I don't think it was recognizably a school uniform.

Comment: Is this definitely a Japanese, black&white manga? Any idea what the target demographic of this was? "female protagonist" usually means shoujo/josei, but "curvaceous female demon" is extremely shonen/seinen.

Comment: @qazmlpok: I do remember it being a black and white Japanese manga. The general feeling was somewhat dark. I have vague memories of the protagonist feeling like she was being forced into her current role, forgoing her art dreams to do what her family needed, and after she gets her powers, she has monsters after her.

Comment: Can you clarify "typical westernish manga features"? Do you mean this takes place in a vaguely European/medieval fantasy world?

Comment: More that it's the usual anime style where they didn't look noticeably Japanese, but honestly, I don't have a firm idea of where it was set, and the grandmother's house feels more like the Victorian/Gothic kind of architecture than something noticeably Japanese.